# Converting 7 Aug 2012 to php date format

Tags: php, iphone, date, mobile

I'm creating a mobile version of a website. On the normal version we just use a jquery date picker to select the date. I haven't added anything like this yet on the mobile version because It seemed my Iphone was smart enough to realise it was a date field and give you date scrollers.

But after I've selected the date it's coming up at 7 Aug 2012 which raises a few questions for me... is this standard? or am I going to have to code for different date formats coming from different phones?

Would it be best to use a jquery date picker? (I'm not sure this would be very tidy).

What's the best way to convert a date like this into a format that php and my database can handle. I have done a bit of looking around google but haven't found much as of yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
    $today = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('7 Aug 2012'));
    echo $today;
?>
```

gives `2012-08-07`

You can change its output by altering `Y-m-d` in `date()`

Refer [this!](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Comment: ah thanks! I'd already tried something like that but I had a stupid error in my code which meant it wasn't working.

Answer (score 1):

`$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('j M Y', '7 Aug 2012');` is the most robust way to do it if you know the format. `strtotime` guesses which isn't necessarily a good thing, and you won't be informed (i.e. an exception won't be thrown) if the date is in a bad format.

See the manual here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the date format is standard. It is very probable that it is affected by the user settings (eg. locale). Eg. if the user defines a Portuguese locale I think the date would be a little bit different.

Using jquery date picker you have the advantage of being able to specify your [desired format](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-dateFormat) (applying the `dateFormat` option). Then you could safely write a PHP script that reads the date in your defined format. You can use PHP's `date()` function as specified by @Bhuvan Rikka.